# Why a user is unable to login in spring boot application?

Tags: java, maven, jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have developed a `spring boot` application (`SpringBootWebSecurity`) with `ThymeLeaf` and `Gradle`. A user can login using the `thymeleaf` form.

Then I developed another new application (`SpringBootJSP`) maintaining the previous structure  (in `SpringBootWebSecurity`) but this time I just changed build tool (`maven`) and view (`jsp`) with proper dependencies. Database and other credentials remain same for both applications. User(s) is/are unable to login with `jsp` application.

**Structures**

```
![application structures][1]
```

**LoginCtroller.java**

```
package com.maxpro.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class LoginController {

    private final String BASE_PATH = "/login";
    private final String LOGIN_PAGE = BASE_PATH + "/login";

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return LOGIN_PAGE;
    }

}
```

**view**

`login.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3"
>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link th:href="@{/css/admin/admin.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${param.error}">
        <strong>Invalid username or password or both.</strong>
    </div>

    <form class="form-signin" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading text-center">sign in</h2>
        <input type="text" id="inputName" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"
               required="required" autofocus="autofocus"/>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
               required="required"/>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>

</div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
</html>
```

`login.jsp`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--  home.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value = "/css/admin/admin.css"/>"/>
    <!-- /home.css -->

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

    <c:if test="${param.error}">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Invalid username or password or both.</strong>
        </div>
    </c:if>

    <form class="form-signin" action="<c:url value="/login"/>" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading text-center">sign in</h2>
        <input type="text" id="inputName" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"
               required="required" autofocus="autofocus"/>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
               required="required"/>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>

</div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
</html>
```

**WebSecurityConfigurer.java & WebUserDetailsService.java** (these classes used to propcess user login)

`WebSecurityConfigurer.java`

```
package com.maxpro.configuration.security;

import com.maxpro.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return new WebUserDetailsService(userRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/css/**", "/img/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login")
                            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
                .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
//                .and()
//                    .csrf();
        ;
    }

}
```

`WebUserDetailsService.java`

```
package com.maxpro.configuration.security;

import com.maxpro.entity.Role;
import com.maxpro.entity.User;
import com.maxpro.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


@Transactional
public class WebUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public WebUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        try {
            User user = userRepository.findByUserName(username);
            if (user == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(), getAuthorities(user));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
    }

    private Set<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(User user) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
            GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName());
            authorities.add(grantedAuthority);
        }
        return authorities;
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

In `SpringBootWebSecurity` application:

```
#configurations
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext

#initializations
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=false

#credentials
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_boot_security
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=ENC(fwPDBYsbkbHVwxDGEsutsQ==)
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/data/schema.sql
```

In case of `SpringBootJSP` application following lines added:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

application.message: Hello World!!

.
.
.

## following line commented
#spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/data/schema.sql
```

**Observations**

In case of login form of `SpringBootWebSecurity` hits on `WebUserDetailsService.java` class. On the other hand, `SpringBootJSP` could not do that.

**Question**

Why is this happening in case of `SpringBootJSP`?

**Projects Location**

1. https://github.com/engrjislam/SpringBootWebSecurity
2. https://github.com/engrjislam/SpringBootJSP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `csrf` is the fact to login / logout a uesr to the website. I should either -

1. Disable `csrf`

... or ...

2. Add `csrf` token to the login form as follows

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
   ```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904252/spring-boot-security-using-jsp-as-view-engine-logout-does-not-work) idea is shared. Thanks @Ken Bekov and @agthumoe to save my day!!